# Permutations of a list - Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I want to make all possible combinations of subgroups with 2 lists. Here is a function that does just this:

```
getCombinations :: [a] -> [[a]]
getCombinations na = do
    a <- na
    b <- na
    [[a,b]]
```

If you pass "abc" to this function, it returns this:

```
["aa","ab","ac","ba","bb","bc","ca","cb","cc"]
```

A simple modification of the same method could return combinations of 3 lists instead of two.

```
getCombinations :: [a] -> [[a]]
getCombinations na = do
    a <- na
    b <- na
    c <- na
    [[a,b,c]]
```

Result of passing "abc" as an argument:

```
["aaa","aab","aac","aba","abb","abc","aca","acb","acc",
"baa","bab","bac","bba","bbb","bbc","bca","bcb","bcc",
"caa","cab","cac","cba","cbb","cbc","cca","ccb","ccc"]
```

What's the simplest way to make it scale to an arbitrary number of lists? Here is what the type declaration should look like:

```
getCombinations :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

Comment: You can always try to use hoogle: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[[a]], it gives replicateM as third result.

Comment: Thanks sdcvvc, I didn't know it was possible to query hoogle like that!

Comment: Technically, these are [Permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) NOT [Combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). Mathematicians will be pedantic...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What you want is [`replicateM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html#v:replicateM):

```
replicateM :: Int -> m a -> m [a]
```

The definition is as simple as:

```
replicateM n = sequence . replicate n
```

so it's `sequence` on the list monad that's doing the real work here.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of anwswer I was looking for. Thanks a lot ehird!

Comment: @RooSoft Why would you expect anything less?  Especially on SO.  Especially for the [haskell] tag (the friendliest tag on SO).

Comment: How cruel of you, embarrassing me like that. Here is what I had: `\i l->iterate(ap(fmap(:)l))[[]]!!i` T_T

Comment: @AdamWagner That's even more awesome if I can make friends while networking about this lovely language! :)

Answer (score 19):

For those come here for the [combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) function, a ***k***-combination of a set **S** is a subset of *k* distinct elements of **S**, note that the order doesn't matter.

Choose `k` elements from `n` elements equals choose `k - 1` elements from `n - 1` elements plus choose `k` elements from `n - 1` elements.

[image]

Use this recursive definition, we can write:

```
combinations :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combinations k xs = combinations' (length xs) k xs
  where combinations' n k' l@(y:ys)
          | k' == 0   = [[]]
          | k' >= n   = [l]
          | null l    = []
          | otherwise = map (y :) (combinations' (n - 1) (k' - 1) ys) ++ combinations' (n - 1) k' ys 


ghci> combinations 5 "abcdef"
["abcde","abcdf","abcef","abdef","acdef","bcdef"]
```

The op's question is a repeated permutations, which someone has already given an answer. For non-repeated permutation, use `permutations` from Data.List.