# Haskell unknown size list comprehension

Tags: haskell

I have to generate all possible lists of numbers meeting some requirements.
I know how to to this for fixed sized size chain.
Pseudocode:

```
[ [x1,x2,x3]| x1<-[1..5],x2<-[20..30], x2 `basedOn` x1, x3<-[100..110], x3 `basedOn` x1+x2]
```

where basedOn is some boolean filter.

But how to do it the length of chain is determined at runtime, aka variable?

I have different set generated for each `Xn`. So basically what I wanna do is to generate sets for `X1,X2..Xn`. Then I want to pick one element from `X1` and pick one element from `X2` that not colides with `X1` Then I want To pick one from `X3` not colliding with `X1` and `X2` and so on to `Xn`. And When I have one result. I want it to pick others from Xn meeting requirements. Then back to `Xn-1` pick another valid and then back to `Xn` again and generate all not colliding again. And then I want to return deeper and so on. It's what list comprehension does, but I want it for dynamic size.

I know list compehension is syntactic sugar so to generate it dynamically I probably have to use monads, but I have no idea how to :)
Could you help me how to achieve this in Haskell?

Comment: With the help of recursion. You might have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658409/haskell-combinations-and-permutation or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779765/combinations-of-a-list

Answer (score 2):

Using recursion inside list comprehension itself:

```
import Data.Maybe

basedOn :: Int -> Int -> Bool
basedOn a b = even (a+b)

func :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
func a = myFun a Nothing where
  myFun :: [[Int]] -> Maybe Int -> [[Int]]
  myFun [] _ = [[]]
  myFun (xs:xss) j  = [[a] ++ b | a <- xs, b <- myFun xss (next j a), pred j a]
                    where
                      pred Nothing _ = True
                      pred (Just x) a = a `basedOn` x
                      next Nothing a = Just a
                      next (Just x) a = Just (x+a)

main = putStr $ show $ func [[1..5] , [6..10], [11..15]]
```

Comment: Seems like what I need. Do I understand well than j is accumulator that adds further elements to baseOn set. And pred is filtering function that add a if set's empty or based on BasedOn filter after.