# Monadic way for list comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, monads

I have the following function

```
combinations :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
combinations []       = [[]]
combinations (xs:xss) = concat [map (x:) yss | x <- xs]
  where yss = combinations xss
```

Which produces all combinations between its elements:

```
*Main> combinations [[1,2],[2,3,4],[5,6]]
[[1,2,5],[1,2,6],[1,3,5],[1,3,6],[1,4,5],[1,4,6],[2,2,5],[2,2,6],[2,3,5],[2,3,6]
,[2,4,5],[2,4,6]]
```

I some how feel there must be a monadic way to do this

```
foobar = do
    n <- [1,2]
    ch <- [3,4,5]
    return[n,ch]
```

This is how far I came. But I am stuck.

Comment: It's very similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779765/combinations-of-a-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I've been able to come up with is

```
combinations [] = [[]]
combinations (xs:xss) = do
    x <- xs
    ys <- combinations xss
    return $ x : ys
```

---

The way I derived this was I first converted the list comprehension into monadic code (which also meant dropping the `concat` to get it to type check)

```
combinations (xs:xss) =
    let yss = combinations xss
    in do
        x <- xs
        map (x:) yss
```

Then I realized that `map (x:) yss` is exactly `fmap (x:) yss`, which is exactly `yss >>= return . (x:)`, so I knew I could do

```
combinations (xs:xss) =
    let yss = combinations xss
    in do
        x <- xs
        ys <- yss
        return $ x : ys
```

And then it can be inlined as

```
combinations (xs:xss) = do
    x <- xs
    ys <- combinations xss
    return $ x : ys
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function is [`sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v%3asequence) for the list monad.

```
> :t sequence
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
> sequence [[1,2],[2,3,4],[5,6]]
[[1,2,5],[1,2,6],[1,3,5],[1,3,6],[1,4,5],[1,4,6],[2,2,5],[2,2,6],[2,3,5],[2,3,6],
[2,4,5],[2,4,6]]
```

Comment: thanks, your answer would be the obvious choice. But I accepted @bheklilr his answer, because it was nearer to my thought process.